# Вывод переменных в JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Простая страница

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <c:set var="test" value="TestVariable"/>
        <c:out value="${test}">Fail</c:out>
    </body>
</html>
```

На выходе получается

```
<html>
    <body>
        
        ${test}
    </body>
</html>
```

Что я делаю не так? почему выводится `${test}`, а не `TestVariable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `web.xml` вместо написал `<web-app>`

```
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
```

все заработало